# What happens when you mv a folder that a docker container volume is using?

Tags: docker, docker-run

Say I run a container like so:

```
docker run -v /host/folder:/data some-image
```

if we run `mv /host/folder /host/folder2`, I am sure bad stuff will happen, and the only solution is to stop the container and restart it?

Answer (score 2):

Docker uses bind mounts a la `mount --bind` to make volumes available.

Bind mounts behave a lot like hard links. If you hard link `foo` to `bar` with `ln foo bar`, you can rename or remove `foo` and it won't affect `bar` because both files point to the same inode. Similarly, if you bind `foo` to `bar` with `mount --bind foo bar`, moving or removing `foo/` won't affect `bar/`.

Let's take a look with two test directories `foo` and `bar`:

```sh
$ mkdir foo bar
$ touch foo/FOO bar/BAR
$ ls foo/
FOO
$ ls bar/
BAR
```

If we mount `foo` on top of `bar` and then rename `foo`, `bar` is unaffected:

```sh
$ sudo mount --bind foo bar
$ ls bar/
FOO
$ mv foo foo.renamed
$ ls bar/
FOO
```